# Extracting depth buffer to array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, opengl

I'm attempting to extract the depth buffer from OpenGL to an array on the CPU.

The code I have below (somewhat modified as original is an existing component designed to extract the rendered image and does so successfully) "works", but always returns exactly 0.

```
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, buffer);
int size = w*h*sizeof(GLubyte);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, size, NULL, GL_STREAM_READ);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
GLubyte* depth = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
return depth;
```

I've attempted a `glReadBuffer(GL_DEPTH)` after the `glBindBuffer` call, as well as using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` (something which every resource recommends but no-one seems to explain why), but both produce invalid enum errors. GL_DEPTH_TEST is enabled, and there is no errors being generated.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me and this could be way off is that you are reading the depth buffer as a byte, which should cause all bytes to be either 0 or 1; if nothing in your scene is at a saturated depth value, you will probably only see zeroes unless you read it as GL_FLOAT.

Just a thought.

Comment: GL_FLOAT had produced similar results, but everything was white. Changed to use GL_INT (and right-shifting the depth values by 8, which I read in another source was necessary, the image was entirely grey otherwise), which is extracting the depth buffer, but something is messed up. The image shows four sub-images that's clearly the depth map, each 1/4 the size (so the bottom 3/4 is solid grey), but with variations, almost as though the bytes were interleaved somehow.

Comment: [`glReadBuffer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadBuffer.xml) does not accept `GL_DEPTH`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a depth buffer:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint pbo = 0;
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex3i( -1, -1, 0 );
    glVertex3i(  1, -1, 0 );
    glVertex3i(  1,  1, 0 );
    glVertex3i( -1,  1, 0 );
    glEnd();

    int w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    int h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, w * h * sizeof( GLfloat ), 0, GL_STREAM_READ );
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0 );
    GLfloat* ptr = (GLfloat*)glMapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY );
    if( ptr )
    {
        // look for values of ~0.5 here in ptr...
    }
    glUnmapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 128, 128 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();

    glGenBuffers( 1, &pbo );

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The depth buffer is enabled. Using GL_FLOAT produces all 1.0s. Using GL_INT I get an image, though depth values scale from black to white multiple times through various depths (ie, an object scaled along the depth axis starts at black when closest, continues through grey to white, then jumps back to black and repeats). The 1/4 size issue described in the comment above turned out to be an issue with the image structure. Other than using GL_INT instead of GL_FLOAT (and no GLUT), my gl code is the same as your's.

Comment: The best description of the effect I can come up with is "Beetlejuicing", and it's highly sensitive to the near clipping plane (further plane -> more repeated black/white gradients).

Comment: @MikeBarriault: It sounds like you're trying to represent this as an RGB bitplane image without any of the appropriate steps. What you should do is divide each pixel (the entire 32-bit? integer) by INT_MAX and then multiply by 255 and assign this value to R, G and B if you want to visualize this as a color image. Basically, you're dealing with fixed-point normalization.

Comment: @MikeBarriault: That is a very funny way of describing the phenomenon though. I will have to remember that :)